# file_get_contents, curl, get_headers, .. returns nothing

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, get-headers

I'm trying to get the content of an external file (youtube json feed)
I first tried using `file_get_contents()` and curl.
None of them are giving me any response.

In php.ini `allow_url_fopen` is set to On. And I also tried turning off safe mode.

```
error_reporting('E_ALL');
ini_set('display_errors',1);
echo file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/760E7F6C9B5CD71E?v=2&alt=json');
```

What can be going wrong?

Comment: its `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, also did you check your server log, perhaps you have some kind of restriction. Just lookup your config to see everything installed with `<?php phpinfo();?>`

Comment: Changed it to error_reporting(E_ALL);
Getting: failed to open stream: Network is unreachable in file.php

Comment: Some hosts have an outgoing connection firewall type thing, perhaps its set to deny all.

Comment: Is there any way to figure out if the server has such a firewall? I use a shared hosting with plesk installation.

Comment: Well your getting an error that suggests as much, look around your control panel for `Server > IP Addresses > Firewall` or similar, if your stuck open a ticket to your host and get them to fix it.

Comment: create a ticket to your hosting provider, they can tell if they have disabled it on purpose or not...

Comment: Thanks, I hope they can fix it

Answer (score 1):

Use curl instead of file_get_contents. Something like this:

```
$url  = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/760E7F6C9B5CD71E?v=2&alt=json';
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Comment: I got no errors and no response.
Script online: http://test.odb-competition.be/test.php

Comment: If you get "Network is unreachable" error then it's a network problem and you may contact with your hosting company.

Comment: @cloetensbrecht you can enable error reporting in your php.ini file in order to see your php errors.